# Teamviewer and fullscreen directx app

Tags: c#, directx

I've been building a 3D engine from scratch using C# and I've tried to show the result to a friend of mine using Teamviewer. When my demo game starts he doesn't see it.
He can only see the last active program on my screen (for example visual studio from which I started the game)

The game engine launches a windows form at start, then directx binds to this form.
It's a fullscreen application with no windows forms borders etc.

Why doesn't teamviewer pick this up?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I think teamviewer uses it's own display driver, that could be the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeamViewer uses a display [mirror driver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_driver) to accelerate remote viewing of the screen. Mirror drivers mirror the drawing operations of the normal screen, however, because your 3D app uses a hardware accelerated drawing surface, it is not mirrored to the mirror driver.

It's not just because it's full screen either, even in a window, the viewer would likely see just a black box where your 3D app should be.

Comment: This makes sense, is there any way around it, albeit only for demo purposes?

Comment: @thomas Not that I know of. You could maybe use some kind of VNC application without a mirror driver, but it would be dead slow for the remote person.

Comment: Actually I can see any directx game's screen.. I think the trick is in the "show background" option.